# How to install Django Rest Framework using Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, anaconda, conda

Main OS I am using are Ubuntu and Windows.

I couldn't find the package in conda.I am using python 3.5.

Comment: Does not say that it is valid for several OS in the labels? https://anaconda.org/ioos/djangorestframework I read  linux-64, win-32, win-64, osx-64

Comment: ya. it works. I am using it together with apache and wsgi. Thank you. Btw, how did you search, is there any ui to search the package?

Comment: Just googled "conda djangorestframework". The only other interface I know is conda via command line http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/conda-search.html

Answer (score 6):

DRF is now on conda-forge. You can install it by using:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install djangorestframework
```

More information about conda-forge:
https://conda-forge.github.io/

Answer (score 3):

I have installed it on win7 and ubuntu 16.10.
To install this package with conda run:

```
conda install -c anaconda django=1.10.5

activate myenv             # windows cmd
source activate myenv      # linux, MacOS

# Anaconda prompt

 pip install djangorestframework
 pip install markdown       # Markdown support for the browsable API.
 pip install django-filter  # Filtering support

# verify 

 conda list                 # Now you should see it on your list
```

Comment: Thanks but I asked for Django Rest Framework, not Django. @giosans already answered that in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

django takes care of much of the hassle of Web development, so you can focus on writing your app without needing to reinvent the wheel. To install this package with conda run https://anaconda.org/anaconda/django :

```
conda install -c anaconda django
```

I just installed  django 1.11.3 on Python 3.6.2  Anaconda, Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted inside the question:

The easiest is to go in to conda environment and use pip inside to install Django by doing:

```
> activate $your_conda_env
> pip install djangorestframework
```

Answer (score 0):

just typing

```
pip install django
pip install djangoframework
```

or use a virtual environment to install those packages for that, first you need to install a virtual environment

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then create a new directory and make new virtual environment eg:

```
mkdir django
cd django
virtualenv django_project1
source django_project1/bin/activate
pip install django
pip install djangoframework
```

this will install django framework inside the virtual environment

will install django framework in your computer. And also update your pip packages using

```
pip update $PKG_NAME
```

eg:

```
pip update python
```